# Short sequences of vector bundles induce long exact sequence in sheaf cohomology

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

If $0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles how I can prove that there is a short exact sequence of the sheaves of the sections? I know that this is a well known proof and I want use this to check that there is a long exact sequence in the sheaf cohomology. Can you help me to prove this? It's good also a reference of a book that proves this fact. Thanks in advance.